# Prettier double and single quotes in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, prettier

I facing some problems since i started to learn react and using prettier to format jsx files.

i wish it format to double with double quotes only the html inside jsx.

eg. I have this simple component

```
import React from "react";

function NotFound() {
  return <div data-testid="page-not-found">NotFound</div>;
}

export default NotFound;
```

and i wish to format with double quotes, only the html `div` attributes as `data-testid="page-not-found"`

i tried to create a prettier config with the follow rule `"jsxSingleQuote": false`

but it format every quote in the file to double quote eg. `import React from "react";` but in this case i need it to be single quote.

Comment: Do you also have a setting for `singleQuote`?

Comment: you need to go into your prettier settings and check the box that states require prettier config

Comment: @RobertTerrell "Check the box?" Can you explain? OP doesn't mention any editor/IDE/thing-with-boxes and apparently the setting has an effect, just not the one the OP wants.

Comment: Im referring to the settings in the editor.  The user probably forgot to check require prettier config when creating one and thus it doesn't turn off jsx single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"jsxSingleQuote":fasle` and run a script/command in terminal:

```
npx prettier --write .--jsx-single-quote
```